# Why does json.load() not work with json schema?

Tags: python, json, schema, jsonschema

I created a JSON schema. I approved the schema using different online validators, e. g. [Hyperjump.io](https://json-schema.hyperjump.io/). I want to load the schema with `json.load()` in Python, but it always raises the error

> JSONDecodeError: Expecting value

According to [jsonschema](https://github.com/python-jsonschema/jsonschema) it should be possible to load JSON schema using `json.load()`. I tried it with simpler examples without success. I don't know what I'm missing and hope someone can help me out.

My schema:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
  "type": "object",

  "properties":
  {
    "Person":
    {
        "type": "array",
        "title": "Person",
        "items": 
        {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": 
            {
                "FirstName":
                {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            }
        }
    }
  }
}
```

A simpler schema:

```
{
     "$schema": "https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/schema",
     "type": "object",

     "properties": 
     {
        "Person": 
        {
            "type": "string"
        }
     }
}
```

My code:

```
   schema = r"PATH/TO/JSON_FILE.json"
   with open(schema) as schema_file:
        if os.path.splitext(schema)[1] == '.json':
            schema_data = json.load(schema_file)
```

Comment: the code loads both schemas without issues, are you sure of the file content?

Comment: Please show how you're using json.load(). Taking these schemas as strings and using json.loads() they both work as expected

Comment: This work for me too. Are you pointing to the correct file ?

Comment: I don't understand why you check extension `.json` after opening file. And it could be simpler to check `schema.endswith('.json')`